# Java web framework benchmark

Tags: java, frameworks

To compare with django, I would like to find benchmarks on main Java web frameworks (struts, faces etc...)
I searched on google, but I was unable to find a benchmark giving how many req/s java frameworks can handle.

Do you know some benchmarks for a java web framework ?

Answer (score 4):

**Techempower benchmark:**

http://www.techempower.com/benchmarks

They are comparing a lot of frameworks and accept new frameworks for comparison. Interface very intuitive. In my view, it is the best benchmark now.

**World wide wait - 1 hour speech**

http://www.parleys.com/#id=2942&st=5

Django is not here, it's only benchmark of JVM frameworks. But still, it is quite scientific, worth it.

Answer (score 2):

This one was just recently published: http://www.jtict.com/blog/rails-wicket-grails-play-lift-jsp It contains quite many different Java-based frameworks and their response time comparisons.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure that what you are requesting is available. There are too many variables to measure this accurately. It ALL depends on what your web application is doing, and how you do it.

For example, do you use a DB? How do I measure Struts or Faces throughput on something that heavily depends on your schema, your DB hardware, your network setup, and the complexity of your pages?

Do you do any type of intensive processing? How do I measure Struts or Faces throughput on something that heavily depends on your algorithm, data size, memory and processor resources?

I could measure the throughput of Hello World, but how valuable would that be to you? How realistic?

In my experience, the biggest bottleneck with most web applications is NOT the framework. It's the network and/or the DB. The only way to get reliable numbers for this is to make a reasonable proof of concept of *your* application and measure it.

Comment: There are many benchmarks with django, from the simple hello world to more complex like with a template use + DB access. I was expecting the same kind of tests for some java frameworks. But you are right : behind the scene, I wondered whether Java really boost throughput compared to django with the use of one DB...

Comment: My personal experience has always been that the majority of latencies are induced by the network, the DB, or poor implementation (read, doing more work than necessary). I don't believe that any of the established Java frameworks will induce excessive latencies or overheads. Unfortunately, this is only my experience, and therefore suspect. Sorry I don't have benchmarks to point to.

Answer (score 0):

The most current (started on 20/Jul/2019) TechEmpower Web Framework benchmark filtered by

- Java *
- Python Django
- Full Stack
- Full ORM

https://www.techempower.com/benchmarks/#section=test&runid=66ee924e-3bc2-4bd8-aaf0-2cd8443f65db&hw=ph&test=fortune&l=zijzb3-f&c=6&o=e&f=0-0-4fti4g-0-4fti4g-0-b8jk-0-0-0